# MVC controller cannot connect to Web API (in some case)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

```
public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string search)
    {
        List<ArticlesData> articles = new List<ArticlesData>();

        HttpClient client = _api.Initial();

        HttpResponseMessage res;
        if(String.IsNullOrEmpty(search))
        {
            res = await client.GetAsync("api/article");
            
        } else
        {
            res = await client.GetAsync($"api/article/{search}");
        }

        
        if (res.IsSuccessStatusCode)
        {
            var results = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
            articles = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<ArticlesData>>(results);
        }
        return View(articles);
    }
```

1.Up There is Mvc Controller

```
        [HttpGet("{search}")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Articles>> GetSearchedArticles(string search)
        {
            return await _articleService.GetSearched(search);
        }



        [HttpGet]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Articles>> GetAllArticles()
        {
            return await _articleService.GetAll();
        }
```

2. Down there is web api Controller. In first case when getting all articles it works properly, but in search case, program doesn't enter GetSearchedArticles(string search). Any suggestions?

Comment: "res = await client.GetAsync($"api/article/{search}");" - are you sure you are building the url correctly ?

Comment: also, why you do not go async all the way ? Instead of "var results = res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;" you can write "var results = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();"

Comment: Yes url is correct, I will consider your suggestions but main problem is connection between mvc and web api

Comment: What is a search string like? Can you post an example of url with a search when it is not working?

Comment: Can you provide the entire controller class ? I am interested on how the route is defined. Also, can you provide the search string ? Thanks